# uninitialized data and memcpy

Tags: c++, char

Mike Miller says in [240. Uninitialized values and undefined behavior](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#240):

> The wording in 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental] was carefully crafted to allow use of unsigned char to access uninitialized data so that memcpy and such could be written in C++ without undefined behavior

What is meant by that? Why would one want to access uninitialized data?

Comment: @chac yes, to initialize it in other words.

Comment: Weird, I don’t think this passage would actually be necessary, one could always use placement-new to construct into uninitialised values.

Comment: @chac when you write into, do you use a pointer to do so? This pointer would then be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're copying a `struct` which contains padding, `memcpy` will copy the padding too. Generally that padding is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is still possible to access memory not initialized by an object constructor (which is the way intended for C++). We can use *unsigned char* (or byte) to point to raw memory chunks.

Objects are what you should handle, but you can still see memory the way it is.